# Does Rails' fragment caching suit this problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, fragment-caching

I do not understand yet Rails' caching system, but I've read in the guides section of a feature called fragment caching.

My problem is: my view consist mostly in static elements. It is almost completely static, the only changing is a status message and a hidden input field in a form, both generated at every request to the action serving the view.

Is fragment caching suitable for this problem? What caching strategy should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment caching is adequate to your problem. It is adequate because it enables you to cache a part (fragment) of your view, instead of the whole view. From the docs:

> Fragment caching is used for caching
>   various blocks within templates
>   without caching the entire action as a
>   whole. This is useful when certain
>   elements of an action change
>   frequently or depend on complicated
>   state while other parts rarely change
>   or can be shared amongst multiple
>   parties. The caching is done using the
>   cache helper available in the Action
>   View. A template with caching might
>   look something like:

```
<!-- this is the dynamic part-->
<b>Hello <%= @name %></b>

<% cache do %>
  <%= render :partial => "static_part" %>
<% end %>
```

So you can put your static part between the `cache` block, and the dynamic part outside of it.
Here's the link to the relevant docs: [rails fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching).